# $2+4+6+\cdots+2n=n^2+n$ by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove $2+4+6+\cdots +2n=n^2+n$ by mathematical induction.
I followed all the steps and the $P_{k+1}$ was $2+4+6+\cdots+2(k+1)=(k+1)^2+k+1$
Starting from the left hand side of the equation I have solved till $k^2+k+2(k+1)$. 
Now I am stuck here. I don't know how to do it further. Please guide me thanks.

Comment: The formulas are wrong, $2^n$ and $2^{k+1}$ should read $2n$ and $2(k+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if you need $2+4+6+\cdots+2n$ rather than $2+4+6+\cdots+2^n$.

Look at
$$
\underbrace{2+4+6+\cdots+2k}+2(k+1).
$$
The induction hypothesis tells you what to do with the part over the underbrace.  Then massage it a bit with some simple algebra.

Comment: No, its the 2nd one which I want...

Comment: $2+4+6+8+10+12+14+16= 2+4+6+\cdots+2^4$.  Is this equal to $4^2+4$?  If you go from $4$ to $5$, you get $2+4+6+8+10+\cdots+32$, and you've got 8 more terms, not just one more term.

Comment: @Akito If you're trying to prove that $2+4+\ldots+2^n=n^2+n$, it's not surprising that you're having trouble: it's wrong, you won't be able to prove it. Notice that $6$ is $2\times3$, not $2^3$.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for pointing it. Its a wrong proposition

Answer (score 0):

$k^2+k+2(k+1)=k^2+3k+2=k^2+2k+1+(k+1)= (k+1)^2+(k+1)$